# how to define a prometheus metric

Tags: prometheus, grafana, metrics

now i want to monitor some microservice api with prometheus and display with grafana
here is my purposes：

1. monitor a service with 3 apis ,when all api is in trouble at one time means the service is down
2. when upper 3 services is down, the application status is down
3. the grafana display the down service and application status

now i defined a metric like this:
`my_service_api(ok, service_name, api_name)`, and type is guage
and i sended data with pushgateway like this:

```
my_service_api(1, 'service1', 'api1')
my_service_api(1, 'service1', 'api2')
my_service_api(1, 'service1', 'api3')
my_service_api(0, 'service2', 'api1')
my_service_api(0, 'service2', 'api2')
my_service_api(0, 'service2', 'api3')
my_service_api(0, 'service3', 'api1')
my_service_api(0, 'service3', 'api2')
my_service_api(0, 'service3', 'api3')
```

and i can finish the purpose one with promSql
 `(sum(my_service_api) by (service_name) ) < bool 3`

how could i finish the rest? maybe my metric is not useful?